# Prove that a given function is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

Consider the following convex set:

$$S = \{m \in \mathbb{R}^N : m_i \geq 0 \text{ }\forall i=1, \ldots, N \wedge \sum_{i=1}^Nm_i = 1\}$$

and following function $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

$$f(m) = \sum_{j=1}^M \left(X_j - \sum_{i=1}^NY_{i,j}m_i\right)^2$$

I need to prove that $f(m)$ is convex on the set $S$.
Some tips?

If I prove that $f(m)$ is convex and I know that another function $g(m)$ is convex, then can I say that $h(m) = f(m) + g(m)$ is convex too?